# Why to I need to keep putting in my passwords after my Mac sleeps?

Tags: email, password

I have several email accounts, and I keep having to put in the email passwords, my login details and my system passwords! I think it happens when my Mac has slept - overnight etc? Help!!?

Comment: and you did not set it up that way? to ask for password on wake ?

Comment: No - I checked that in Security settings.I have a few silly things gong wrong suddenly- e.g. my microphone won't work and when I test it the mike feedback is all greyed out. Perhaps I need to re boot my entire system??

Comment: maybe, but for now run the disk permissions repair in disk utility app in your utility folder.

Comment: Nope - it is still forgetting them - any other ideas??

Comment: you already accepted a answer ? did that not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a keychain issue.

First port of call is to open 'keychain access' Then in Keychain Access Menu run keychain first aid.